# Why is my TCP connection closing?

Tags: vb.net, tcp, tcpclient

I have developed an application for my game server. Now, in this application when I press "Connect" it sends data to my Game Server. And it does, but, the problem is, when it sends the connection it automatically closes it, and I don't want to close it because I have a socket plugin that kills the TCP connection after player leaves the game. Now on my localhost it works, the TCP doesn't "die" but on my vps it disconnects, can someone please check my code and see if I'm doing something wrong?

```
Dim p() As Process
                            Dim gta() As Process

                            p = Process.GetProcessesByName("samp")
                            gta = Process.GetProcessesByName("gta_sa")

                            If p.Count > 0 Then
                                MsgBox("Vec imate pokrenut SAMP - ugasite ga.")

                            ElseIf gta.Count > 0 Then
                                MsgBox("Vec imate pokrenut GTA San Andreas - ugasite ga.")

                            Else


                                Try
                                    Dim prozess As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("samp")(0)
                                    prozess.Kill()
                                Catch ex As Exception

                                End Try
                                My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SAMP", "PlayerName", TextBox1.Text)
                                Process.Start("samp://164.132.229.172:7777")



                                Dim client As New TcpClient()
                                client.Connect("164.132.229.172", 7775)
                                Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text)

                                Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
                                stream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

                                Timer1.Start()

                            End If

                        End If
```

Timer:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim pd() As Process
    pd = Process.GetProcessesByName("Aimbot By The2Gamers")
    If pd.Count > 0 Then
        Dim InternetExplorer() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Aimbot By The2Gamers")
        For Each Process As Process In InternetExplorer
            Process.Kill()
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Now this part down here is only server log from my vps:

> [01:12:15] [LAUNCHER] Connection to Socket Server. | ClientID: [0] |
>   ClientIP: [92.241.153.29]  [01:12:15] Remote client [0] has sent:
>   Joan_Mackey [01:12:16] [LAUNCHER] Player Socket disconnected|
>   ClientID: [0] | PlayerID: [0]

Comment: The timer is causing the problem, where do i start timer ?

Comment: When i put my code like this, TCP stops itself, but when i remove the timer it works:

Comment: Tested it again, whenever i try to check if some process is running in this timer it will kill the TCP

Comment: This lacks code for us to be able to tell what the problem is... In what places are you closing the TcpClient? Do you know if the TcpClient was closed by normal code or if it's explicitly terminated for some other reason?

Comment: Try stepping through your code using breakpoints. They might help you tell what's going on.

Comment: I am not closing TcpClient because it will be closed in my other app, which is listening to it, i dont udnerstand these breakpoints, can you explain a little bit more ?

Comment: Okey, i've edited the post with more code

Comment: [MSDN - Using Breakpoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx). And the new code is irrelevant to your problem. It's what happens after the connection is established that will be relevant, that is, what might cause it to close. I doubt it is the timer as it isn't doing anything with the TcpClient. So without you knowing when/where it disconnects, it'll be really hard for us to help you.

Comment: Yes, but, when i stop using timer, it doesnt disconnect the socket, it works like, i connect to my server, and its ok, but as soon as i start timer, no matter which, it automatically stops the tcp

Comment: _"no matter which"_ - how many timers do you have, and what do they do? Perhaps the timers accidentally kill the client process? How is the server notified about the disconnection?

Comment: Well i should only run the timer that i posted, because i only need that one, i was testing something with autoupdate timer and the same thing happens, it kills the client.

You can see the timer in codes above.

Comment: So both kills the client? Are you currently running the client and server on the same machine, and if so, can you confirm if the entire client process is killed or is it just the connection that is terminated? **EDIT:** Also, is the timer located in the client application?

Comment: No, the application is on localhost, and im connecting to my vps, only connection is killed, timer is located in the same file as the function that is starting the tcp, here is the image:

http://i.imgur.com/n6RGR4Q.png

Comment: Yes but _how_ does the server know that the connection has been terminated? Perhaps it's due to that you stop using the `client` variable once you exit that method?

Comment: It's a game server, which is running socket plugin developed, you can check it here
http://forum.sa-mp.com/showthread.php?t=333934

Comment: So assuming the client is the problem (which it appears to be), my question still remains.

Comment: Well, because it listens to the same port, by the onSocketRemoteDisconnect it detects wether it is still running or not, and i can see that it has been killed, because, i recieve client_id, and if for example i connect with client id 8 and than i start timer and connect again it will start from 8 because it was previously shut down.

Comment: So if the server is aware, that means that the client was shutdown gracefully... It seems like you've hit a tough problem. But do you mind it disconnecting? Because you never re-use the client since you leave it within the current block (a button, or whatever it is). What happens if you move `Dim client As New TcpClient()` out of any Sub or Function?

Comment: Then it works :P Thank you.

Comment: Ok. Writing it as an answer so you can mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the `Dim client As New TcpClient()` initialization to class level. Class level means that you put it outside any method (that is, outside any `Sub` or `Function`).

As it stands, your `TcpClient` is collected by the Garbage Collector after you've exited whatever method you put it in. After you've passed `End Sub` the `TcpClient` is technically no longer used, because you cannot access that specific instance anymore. The Garbage Collector checks for this when it runs, and as your variable is no longer used it will be collected.

When the Garbage Collector collects an object it starts releasing the object's unused resources. If the object (or any child object) implements the `IDisposable` interface, the Garbage Collector will first call that object's `Dispose()` method.

`TcpClients` are built on top of the `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` class. The `Socket` class implements `IDisposable` which means [it has got a `Dispose()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190731.aspx). The Garbage Collector will call this method for the underlying socket of your `TcpClient`. When it is called, the socket will automatically shut itself down and tell the endpoint that it's disconnecting - and this is what you are experiencing.

So to summarize:

1. The `TcpClient` is no longer used after you pass `End Sub`.
2. When the Garbage Collector runs it will start releasing the `TcpClient`'s resources, and call `Dispose()` on the underlying socket.
3. The underlying socket will then tell the endpoint that it's disconnecting, and then it will terminate the connection.
4. Now your connection to the server isn't open anymore.

Comment: @Nathaniel : And now you have a more thorough explanation to why it happened in the first place :). Try to keep it in your mind, that when you want to keep a variable "alive", you should always declare it at class level **UNLESS** it's already referenced somewhere else. -- Good luck with your project!